# How to get a specific part of moment.js / timezone.js date

Tags: javascript, date, variables, momentjs

I am quite low at javascript. I started to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for my project to make javascript code to work by time & date, which always aligned by specific time zone. But I am struggling to understand how access different parts of my variable. My code:

```
var ItalyZone = "Europe/Rome";
var currentTime= moment().tz(ItalyZone).format();
alert(currentTime.hours()); //this is not working....
```

**How can access only hours/minutes of that variable "currenTime" ?
How to set new hours for that variable "currentTime" ?**

Using simple javascript Date() function I could do simply *currentTime.getHours() / currentTime.setHours()*, but how should I do using moment.js ???

Comment: What about format ?
moment().tz(ItalyZone).format("hh") - hours
moment().tz(ItalyZone).format("mm") - minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `format` when you just want the hours, return a date object instead

```
var ItalyZone   = "Europe/Rome";
var currentTime = moment().tz(ItalyZone).toDate(); // return JS date object
var hours       = currentTime.getHours()
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but if I change my Computer/Smart device time it will effect variable hours also. I started to use moment.js to get specific real and not faked time of specific time zone in my project, that clock changes would not effect javascript code.

Comment: In other words: code should not be effected by clock changes on device :)

Comment: What? Of course it changes if you change the computer clock, Moment doesn't solve that, that's an inherit flaw in working with dates clientside, and the only solution is to get the date from the server.

Comment: Oh **** had not tested it very well I think it is wrong option in my case. I will close this topic.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're trying to do, but again, if you want a stable, correct date, you have to get it from the server. Any date gotten clientside would be based on the computer/device internal clock, as that's the only thing that's available in the browser. Moment just makes it easier to format javascript dates, and in your case, set a timezone etc. it still gets the date from the plain javascript `Date` constructor.

Comment: Could you link me to the right direction how to solve this? Options how to get server time?

Comment: Server time is generally easy, just output a timestamp somewhere in the HTML when the server creates the page, and get that with javascript, and you have the time from your server, which most likely is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get-set](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) function to do this

```
moment().minute(Number);
moment().minute(); // Number
moment().minutes(Number);
moment().minutes(); // Number
```

Gets or sets the minutes.

Comment: In my code I have a lot of places where I should compare hours and minutes of my variable currentTime. I need to get it of specific variable "currentTime" your answer not solves my problem: currentTime.moment().minutes(); will not give result for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format to get any part of date time:

```js
var ItalyZone = "Europe/Rome";
    
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("yyyy"); // year
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("MM"); // month
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("DD"); // day
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("hh"); // hours
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("mm"); // minutes
moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("ss"); // seconts

console.log(moment().locale(ItalyZone).format("YYYY MM DD hh mm ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```